# Unable to telnet on ec2 even when HTTPS /port 443 is open

Tags: amazon-ec2, telnet

Settings of my security group on EC2

```
TCP
Port(Service) Source    Action
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   Delete
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0   Delete
```

Output: When I run the telnet

```
JP$ telnet passionate4.net
Trying 50.18.159.124...
telnet: connect to address 50.18.159.124: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

on ubuntu ec2 server

```
ubuntu@ip-10-166-185-18:~$ sudo netstat -nup -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           400/dhclient3
```

Answer (score 3):

Telnet uses port 23, you don't have it in your security group.

Answer (score 0):

type this:
JP$ **telnet passionat4.net 80**

80, 443, 3389, or whatever port you're testing for.

Windows example:
C:/> **telnet www.google.com 80**